# How to count the amount of pins that a particular circuit uses

Tags: boolean-logic

For a circuit like this:

[image]

How do you decide how many pins would be needed? Listening back to the lecture someone declared it as 19, but I don't know where that value has came from.  Could someone explain or the label the diagram for how we get 19 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

19 pins = 9 inputs + 8 outputs + 1 power + 1 ground

Comment: How do you mean power and ground ? do you always add those onto the value ?

Comment: You do when you need to account for 19 pins and only 17 inputs and outputs are shown.  ;-)